# dojo RangeSlider Handles are Positioned Wrong

Tags: css, dojo, position, rangeslider

I am trying to put together a web page that will contain some charts, as well as some RangeSlider widgets to control the data ranges and granularity for the charts. I have created a few  elements to hold various navigation items, and am at the point where I want to place my RangeSliders. Everything is working except that when I click on the shaded bar between the the handles, to move both handles left or right, the handles jump to the right-hand end of the slider bar, and stay there.

I am pretty sure it's due to an incompatibility between my div's absolute/relative positioning, and the slider components, but I'm going nuts trying to get it to work. If I just place the slider with none of my div styles, the slider works, but isn't where I want it.

The entire file is listed below. It's only about 80 lines, including my styling info. I attached it to the divs, rather than drawing it from an external .css file, for simplicity. To try it out, you will need to adjust the paths to the dojo components.

Someone with more expetise than I have can probably scope it out in a jiffy, but I can't seem to reconcile the dojo requirements with my own.

Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Errlog Chart for Single Host</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        @import "1.7.src/dojo/resources/dojo.css";
        @import "1.7.src/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css";
        @import "1.7.src/dijit/themes/dijit.css";
        @import "1.7.src/dijit/tests/css/dijitTests.css";
        @import "1.7.src/dojox/form/resources/RangeSlider.css";
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="1.7.src/dojo/dojo.js" djConfig="isDebug:true, parseOnLoad: true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        dojo.require("dojox.form.RangeSlider");
        dojo.require("dijit.form.HorizontalRule");
        dojo.require("dijit.form.HorizontalRuleLabels");
    </script>
</head>
<body class="tundra">
<div id='header' style="width:100%;
    background: #FC8;
    position: absolute;
    height: 30px;
    top: 0;">header</div>
<div id='middle' style="width:100%;
    background: #8FC;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    bottom: 30px;">
  <div id='left' style="background: #C8F;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;">
  </div>
  <div id='right' style="background: #CF8;
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%;
    top: 0;
    width: 75%;
    height: 100%;">
  <div id='charts' style="background: #DF7;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top:0;
  height:60%;">
CHARTS GO HERE
  </div>
  <div id='sliders' style="background: #BF9;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom:0;
  height:40%;">
SLIDERS GO HERE
    <div 
        id="hrSlider" 
        discreteValues="11"
        onChange="dojo.byId('minValue').value=dojo.number.format(arguments[0][0]/100,{places:1,pattern:'#%'});dojo.byId('maxValue').value=dojo.number.format(arguments[0][1]/100,{places:1,pattern:'#%'});"
        value="20,80" 
        intermediateChanges="true"
        style="width:500px;" 
        dojoType="dojox.form.HorizontalRangeSlider">
        <ol dojoType="dijit.form.HorizontalRuleLabels" container="topDecoration" style="height:1.2em;font-size:75%;color:gray;" count="11" constraints="{pattern:'#.00%'}"></ol>
        <div dojoType="dijit.form.HorizontalRule" container="topDecoration" count=11 style="height:10px;margin-bottom:-5px;"></div>
    </div>
    Horizontal Slider Min Value:<input readonly id="minValue" size="10" value="20.0%"/><br/>
    Horizontal Slider Max Value:<input readonly id="maxValue" size="10" value="80.0%"/><br/>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id='footer' style="width:100%;
    background: #8CF;
    position: absolute;
    height: 30px;
    bottom: 0;">footer</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm still having similar problems with it. It's doing some sort of position calculations and they're apparently wrong, if your layout is more complex than an empty page...

Answer (score 0):

If the difference between min and max is not evenly divisible by the discrete value, odd offsets appear.  Since you don't set min max, they default to 0 and 100.  That is 101 values, which is not evenly divisible by 11